# Connecting application in C to a html form using FCGI

Tags: c, iis-7, fastcgi

I have a html form with hardcoded data.i have added the index file to iis as a website and made it run in the browser.now instead of hardcoding d data i wan to send the input data to form from  C or C++ or C# application thru FCGI.Besides in the form i have written function on clicking ok() for updation of input data and show() to get the updated data from server(data is passed as json).i have commented out the server part in the html form as of now.The html form contains fields like
       FieldName:
       Id:
       Rate://Dropdownbox
       time://radio button
...etc..